# Different behaviour of launchers; Intel vs Raspberry Pi

Tags: launcher, intel, raspberrypi, unity-dash

I have an identical script and an identical .desktop file pinned to the Dash on a Raspberry Pi 4B and an Intel NUC. They behave differently.  On the NUC clicking on the launcher runs the script in a terminal and an indicator dot appears next to the icon on the Dash.  On the Pi the script is run in a terminal but a gnome-terminal-server icon is added to the Dash and the indicator dot is associated with this new icon. I expected the behaviour as seen on the NUC; that is the way it has been for several iterations of Ubuntu.  Is there something different about Ubuntu (or perhaps Gnome) on the Pi.  Just to check I installed older versions of Ubuntu on the Pi and got the same difference as seen in 23.10.

Here are the details of the two machines and screenshots illustrating the different behaviour.

```
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: Mrs-Lovett
       Icon name: computer
      Machine ID: f1cbb61c9a43407db0da4582ef4f3e42
         Boot ID: 01fc9a8755ed4f6483192182db381662
Operating System: Ubuntu 23.10                    
          Kernel: Linux 6.5.0-1008-raspi
    Architecture: arm64
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ 
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ cat ~/.local/bin/StopWatch
#!/bin/bash
echo "STOP"
echo "Watch"
read
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ 
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/StopWatch.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=StopWatch
Icon=StopWatch
Name[en_US]=StopWatch
Name=StopWatch
Exec=gnome-trquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: Mrs-Lovett
       Icon name: computer
      Machine ID: f1cbb61c9a43407db0da4582ef4f3e42
         Boot ID: 01fc9a8755ed4f6483192182db381662
Operating System: Ubuntu 23.10                    
          Kernel: Linux 6.5.0-1008-raspi
    Architecture: arm64
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ 
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ cat ~/.local/bin/StopWatch
#!/bin/bash
echo "STOP"
echo "Watch"
read
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ 
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/StopWatch.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=StopWatch
Icon=StopWatch
Name[en_US]=StopWatch
Name=StopWatch
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=StopWatchTerminal -- /home/rquint/.local/bin/StopWatch
StartupWMClass=StopWatchTerminal
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$ erminal --class=StopWatchTerminal -- /home/rquint/.local/bin/StopWatch
StartupWMClass=StopWatchTerminal
rquint@Mrs-Lovett:~$
```

[image: Mrs-Lovett's desktop]

[image: Mrs-Lovett after clicking on launcher]

```
rquint@Iphigenia:~$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: Iphigenia
       Icon name: computer-desktop
         Chassis: desktop ️
      Machine ID: 8319830a3ff5411e9b72da25dd2dd284
         Boot ID: 5c0bc266e10b413ba178bf63f80f6a32
Operating System: Ubuntu 23.10                    
          Kernel: Linux 6.5.0-14-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Intel_R_ Client Systems
  Hardware Model: NUC8i3BEH
Firmware Version: BECFL357.86A.0051.2018.1015.1513
   Firmware Date: Mon 2018-10-15
rquint@Iphigenia:~$ 
rquint@Iphigenia:~$ cat ~/.local/bin/StopWatch
#!/bin/bash
echo "STOP"
echo "Watch"
read
rquint@Iphigenia:~$ 
rquint@Iphigenia:~$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/StopWatch.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=StopWatch
Icon=StopWatch
Name[en_US]=StopWatch
Name=StopWatch
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=StopWatchTerminal -- /home/rquint/.local/bin/StopWatch
StartupWMClass=StopWatchTerminal
rquint@Iphigenia:~$
```

[image: Iphigenia's desktop]

[image: Iphigenia after clicking on launcher]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Wayland.  Thanks to @waveform80 who answered my original question at [Raspberry Pi Forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=361147)

When you use Xorg there is no problem, but if you login using Wayland you get the unwanted behaviour of an extra icon in the Dash.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? A link only answer is not considered sufficient in this site. Please add the essential steps you used to solve the problem and keep the link as a reference.